# How to OR Loop in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with 100 values and want to pick only specific items from that data set. That's how I do it right now:

`df.match <- subset(df.raw.csv, value == "UC9d" | value == "UCenoM“)`

It's working but I want to solve it with a loop. I tried this but I only get one match. Although I know both values are in the data set.

`for (ID in c("UC9d" , "UCenoM")){df.match <- subset(df.raw.csv, value == ID)}`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you want `%in%` ? Like `df.raw.csv[df.raw.csv$value %in% c("UC9d", "UCenoM"),]`

Comment: Output is one match. One is still missing.

Comment: This works fine for me. ```df.match <- subset(df.raw.csv, value %in% c("UC9d", "UCenoM"))```

Comment: In case you work *interactively* `subset` is OK, but if not the manual recommends *better to use the standard subsetting  functions like `[`*.

Comment: Please share a small subset of data, preferably using `dput()` so it is copy/pasteable.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be not to use loops in R:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mutate(mydata, TOBEINCL = 0) #rename according to your data
```

Create a list of patterns for the match of mydata$ID (^ and $ are for exact matching):

```
toMatch <- c("^UC9d$", "^UCenoM$")
```

Use pattern matching from base R:

```
mydata$TOBEINCL[grep(paste(toMatch,collapse="|"), mydata$ID, ignore.case = FALSE, invert = TRUE)] <- 1
```

Select data:

```
mydataINCL <- mydata[(mydata$TOBEINCL==1) , ]
mydataINCL$ID <- factor(mydataINCL$ID) #sometimes R sticks with the old values
```

Answer (score 1):

An option:

```
df.match <- subset(df.raw.csv, value %in% c("UcenoM", "Uc9d"))
```

Comment: This will not work as expected - you need `%in%` here, not `==`.

Comment: Feel free to  repeat my experiment: 

mydf <- data.frame(name = paste0("product", 1:100), value = sample(rep(c("A","UcenoM", "Uc9d"),200),100)); 

subset(mydf, value==c("UcenoM", "Uc9d"))

Comment: Repeated your experiment. Result is incorrect - misses many rows. Here's a much simpler experiment: `mydf <- data.frame(name = paste0("product", 1:2), value = c("Uc9d", "UcenoM")); subset(mydf, value==c("UcenoM", "Uc9d"))`. The issue is that `==` compares first element to first element, second element to second element, etc. But order does not matter in this case. (Or even more simply, try `c(1, 2) == c(2, 1)`)

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much @GregorThomas for showing me my mistake  very clearly. I have edited my answer based on your correction.